# Purpose of SparkConf and sparkContext

Tags: apache-spark

What’s a purpose of sparkContext and sparkConf ?  Looking for detailed difference.

More than below definition:

Spark Context was the entry point of any spark application and used to access all spark features and needed a sparkConf which had all the cluster configs and parameters to create a Spark Context object.

Answer (score 2):

The first step of any Spark driver application is to create a SparkContext. The SparkContext allows your Spark driver application to access the cluster through a resource manager. The resource manager can be YARN, or Spark's cluster manager. In order to create a SparkContext you should first create a SparkConf. The SparkConf stores configuration parameters that your Spark driver application will pass to SparkContext. Some of these parameters define properties of your Spark driver application and some are used by Spark to allocate resources on the cluster. Such as, the number, memory size and cores uses by the executors running on the workernodes. setAppName() gives your Spark driver application a name so you can identify it in the Spark or Yarn UI.

SparkConf is passed into SparkContext so our driver application knows how to access the cluster.

Now that your Spark driver application has a SparkContext it knows what resource manager to use and can ask it for resources on the cluster. If you are using YARN, Hadoop's resourcemanager (headnode) and nodemanager (workernode) will work to allocate a container for the executors. If the resources are available on the cluster the executors will allocate memory and cores based your configuration parameters. If you are using Sparks cluster manager, the SparkMaster (headnode) and SparkSlave (workernode) will be used to allocate the executors.

Each Spark driver application has its own executors on the cluster which remain running as long as the Spark driver application has a SparkContext. The executors run user code, run computations and can cache data for your application. The SparkContext will create a job that is broken into stages. The stages are broken into tasks which are scheduled by the SparkContext on an executor.

Comment: Where spark driver program exists..? Is it some where within spark-submit shell ...? Or It gets initialised before sparkContext in spark program ..?

Comment: The launch of ```spark-shell``` or ```spark-submit``` signifies that we have created a driver program. The driver application runs our code's main() function and the sparkContext also attaches itself to the spark driver application.

Comment: Kindly review the answer to the question and mark as answer if it solved your issue. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)